# How do you write "deep south"?

Tags: proper-nouns, geography

How does one write "deep south?" It is a proper noun so I believe South is capitalized but what about d/Deep ?

Comment: What research have you done? This site is intended for questions that can not be answered by simple searches. GIYF.

Comment: I ask a question when I "cannot" find a definitive answer. I think this site is intended for exactly that. What exactly is "GIYF?" Maybe one should "Google that" first.

Comment: Users cannot possibly know if questioners have performed some rudimentary search before asking their questions. By sharing your search, it also makes the question more interesting somehow. P.S I had to Google GIYF, I'm more used to seeeing [LMGTFY](https://www.google.it/search?q=LMGTFY&oq=LMGTFY&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to The Chicago Manual of Style, Deep South should be capitalized.

> The **Deep South** is a cultural and geographic subregion in the Southern United States.

Comment: The _Associated Press Stylebook_ agrees with _Chicago_, with the proviso that the term applies specifically to "the region that consists of Alabama, Georgia, Louisiana, Mississippi and South Carolina." All of the states in question have no shared border with any state not a member of the Confederate States of America in the 1860s. I'm not sure why North Carolina doesn't qualify—perhaps because the latter has "North" in its name. Florida would be another obvious member, but evidently it has too many retirees from northern states to make the grade.